# What's meaning of "(=>A-Certain-Type)" in scala?

Tags: scala

Here is a piece of scala codes:

```
var hof: (=> Int) => Int = {r=>r+1}
```

Can anybody explain to me what's meaning of `(=> Int)`? before, i think it's the same to `(() => Int) => Int`, but it's not. I tested it as following:

```
scala> var hof: (=> Int) => Int = {r=>r+1}
hof: (=> Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> hof({()=>1})
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
 required: Int
       hof({()=>1})
```

you can see it's wrong, if i change it to `hof(1)`, if works. Can anybody tell me what's meaning of `(=>A-Certain-Type)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can call this `( => Int)` a code block which evaluates to Int only when called by name.***

**`code: => T` is a call by name parameter**

```
def repeat[T](code: => T)(times: Int): List[T] = {
  (1 to times).toList.map {_ =>  code }
}
```

Consider the above code snippet. `code` in the above function can accept any expression or group of expressions which will evaluate to T. The code block gets evaluated only when it is called by name.

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> repeat { println("hello") }(3)
hello
hello
hello
res2: List[Unit] = List((), (), ())

scala> repeat { println("hello"); 1 }(3)
hello
hello
hello
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)

scala> repeat(println("foo"))(1)
foo
res4: List[Unit] = List(())
```

**Call by name lets you build interesting things like loops**

```
def loop(cond: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit): Unit = {
 if (cond) {
   codeBlock
   loop(cond)(codeBlock)
 } else ()
}
```

Magic happens because of the lazy evaluation of the code block every time it is called by name

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>     def loop(cond: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit): Unit = {
     |      if (cond) {
     |        codeBlock
     |        loop(cond)(codeBlock)
     |      } else ()
     |     }
loop: (cond: => Boolean)(codeBlock: => Unit)Unit

scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> loop(i < 10) { println("foobar"); i += 1}
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
```